# Add header to external link request in Django?

Tags: python, django, http, http-headers, django-admin

I currently am working with the Django admin panel. I have an external link that is in the admin panel that when clicked on, I would like to send a custom header along with the request.

I wrote my own middleware for Django but it doesn't seem to be doing anything for external links, only links that link to other parts of Django admin. Is there another way to add the header to the request for the external link? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain what header and why do you need to send it?

Comment: Its a header for authentication that we are using for one stack (django based) and I need to send this header to be used in another stack (flask)

Comment: So as @Alasdair said there is no way you can do this via clickable link on interface. You can workaround it by passing a query parameter in link and allowing authorisation in flask via query param.

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks on a link, the request is sent by the user's browser, not by your Django application.

It is not possible for Django to make the user's browser send particular http headers.

You could use javascript to send headers (e.g. using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)), but this would only work for ajax requests.